# Parse HTML with PHP do not remove all the html tag?

Tags: php, html

I want to parse html using the php.
My html file is like this

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="text">
    Welcom to Stackoverflow
    </div>
</div>
```

now i want to extract the only this part

```
 <div class="text">
        Welcom to Stackoverflow
        </div>
```

for this i create the code like this

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$tags = $xpath->query('//div[@class="main"]');
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    var_dump(trim($tag->nodeValue));
}
```

this code gives only the

```
Welcom to Stackoverflow
```

but i want the tag also. how to do this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to have the div with class "text" try this:

Change your query to: `$xpath->query('//div[@class="text"]');`
For the output you need: `echo $dom->saveHTML( $tag );`

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$tags = $xpath->query('//div[@class="text"]');
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    echo $dom->saveHTML( $tag );
}
```

Comment: @HiteshShukla: you're welcome, if life saving becomes that easy ;)

Answer (score 0):

The Querypath library for html/xml parsing makes such things much much easier.